# JqGrid not always passing hidden parameters

Tags: jqgrid

When I'm trying to save all rows from jqGrid table, hidden parameters are not always passed to controller. For example when I have 20 rows to save, 3 are without hidden parameters and the rest 17 are ok. I have 4.8.0 version of jqGrid. My question is if it is something wrong in my code or just some error in jqGrid

```
$.each($(gridObject.TableId).jqGrid('getDataIDs'), function (i, val) {
                $(gridObject.TableId).jqGrid('editRow', val, true);
                $(gridObject.TableId).saveRow(val, undefined, gridObject.ControllerAddress + 'Edit', undefined);

            });
```

[Wrong passed parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHEN7.png)

[Correct passed parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9A4Z.png)

Table definition:

```
$(gridObject.TableId).jqGrid({
        url: gridObject.ControllerAddress + 'Get',
        postData:
            {
                forSessionId: gridObject.PostData.ForSessionId,
                pepper: Math.random()
            },
        colNames: ['Participant',
            'Attended <input type="checkbox" id="allAttended" />',
            'Passed <input type="checkbox" id="allPassed" />',
            'Id', 'UserId', 'SessionId'],
        colModel: [

            // displayed always
            { name: 'ParticipantName' },
            {
                name: 'Attended', sortable: false, edittype: 'checkbox', formatter: 'checkbox', formatoptions: { disabled: false },editable: true,
                editoptions: {
                    value: GridsDictionaries.Checkbox.Default.value,
                    dataEvents: [{
                        type: 'change', fn: function (e) {
                            if ($(this).prop('checked')==false) {

                                var passedCheckbox = $(this).closest('tr').find('td[aria-describedby=participations_table_Passed] input[type=checkbox]');
                                $(passedCheckbox).removeProp('checked');
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'Passed', sortable: false, edittype: 'checkbox', formatter: 'checkbox', formatoptions: { disabled: false }, editable: true,
                editoptions: {
                    value: GridsDictionaries.Checkbox.Default.value,
                    dataEvents: [{
                        type: 'change', fn: function (e) {
                            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                                var attendedCheckbox = $(this).closest('tr').find('td[aria-describedby=participations_table_Attended] input[type=checkbox]');
                                $(attendedCheckbox).prop('checked', true);
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }
            },

        // hidden
        { name: 'Id', hidden: true, key: true },
        { name: 'ParticipantId', hidden: true, editable: true },
        { name: 'SessionId', hidden: true, editable: true },

        ],
        autowidth: true,
        pager: "",
        caption: "List of participants",
        //ondblClickRow: gridObject.ToggleEdition, onPaging: gridObject.OnPaging,
        loadComplete: function () {
            $.each($(gridObject.TableId).jqGrid('getDataIDs'), function (i, val) {
                $(gridObject.TableId).jqGrid('editRow', val, true);
                $(gridObject.TableId + ' tr#' + val).unbind('keydown');
            });
        },            
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a error in the code, but feature. As of the creation of jqGrid the hidden fields are not editable and its values are not posted a to the server (local data).

I highly recommend you to discover the documentation of [Guriddo jqGrid](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/editing/#editable).

In the link above is explained how to edit these fields.